# appendTo y prependTo con javascript nativo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quisiera saber como ejecuto las funciones de jQuery "appendTo" y "prependTo" con Javascript puro.
adjunto un ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.item').appendTo('.contenedor');
});
```

```css
.item{
  border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
.contenedor{
  border:1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item">Item</div>
<div class="item">Item</div>
<div class="item">Item</div>
<div class="item">Item</div>

<div class="contenedor"></div>
```

Comment: Lo puedes hacer con `insertAdjacentHTML()` Más información en: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar con este código de `JavaScript` puro.

```js
//get items from HTML
var item = document.getElementsByClassName("item");

for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
  //add to contenedor
  document.getElementById('contenedor').appendChild(item[i]);
}
```

```css
.item{
  border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
.contenedor{
  border:1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor" id="contenedor"></div>
<div class="item">Item</div>
<div class="item">Item</div>
<div class="item">Item</div>
<div class="item">Item</div>
```

Saludos !!!